# How do I use the Django rest framework to prolong a JWT session token?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-authentication, django-contrib

I'm using Django 3.2 with the django.auth.contrib app and djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0.  How do I prolong/reissue a new session token upon receiving a request for an authenticated resource and validating the user can access that resource?  I use the following serializer and view to login the user and issue the initial token

```
class UserLoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=128, write_only=True)
    token = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, read_only=True)

    def validate(self, data):
        username = data.get("username", None)
        password = data.get("password", None)
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is None:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                'A user with this email and password is not found.'
            )
        try:
            payload = JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER(user)
            jwt_token = JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER(payload)
            update_last_login(None, user)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                'User with given email and password does not exists'
            )
        return {
            'username':user.username,
            'token': jwt_token
        }

class UserLoginView(RetrieveAPIView):

    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = UserLoginSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        response = {
            'success' : 'True',
            'status code' : status.HTTP_200_OK,
            'message': 'User logged in successfully',
            'token' : serializer.data['token'],
            }
        status_code = status.HTTP_200_OK

        return Response(response, status=status_code)
```

I have this in my settings file to keep the session to 1 hour initially

```
JWT_AUTH = {
    # how long the original token is valid for
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(hours=1),

}
```

The client submits the session token in the "Authorization" header and it is validated (for example) using the below view

```
class UserProfileView(RetrieveAPIView):

    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    authentication_class = JSONWebTokenAuthentication

    def get(self, request):
        try:
            token = get_authorization_header(request).decode('utf-8')
            if token is None or token == "null" or token.strip() == "":
                raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Authorization Header or Token is missing on Request Headers')
            decoded = jwt.decode(token, settings.SECRET_KEY)
            username = decoded['username']
            
            status_code = status.HTTP_200_OK
            response = {
                'success': 'true',
                'status code': status_code,
                'message': 'User profile fetched successfully',
                'data': {
                        #...
                    }
                }

        except Exception as e:
            status_code = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
            response = {
                'success': 'false',
                'status code': status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
                'message': 'User does not exists',
                'error': str(e)
                }
        return Response(response, status=status_code)
```

What I would like to do in my response is send a new session token down to the user that is good for another hour but I'm unclear what call I need to make to generate such a token and/or edit/invalidate the existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to change a JWT after it is issued, so you can not extend its lifetime, but you can do something like this:

```py
for every request client makes:
    if JWT is expiring:
       generate a new JWT and add it to the response
```

And the client will use this newly issued token.
for this, you can add a [django middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/middleware/):
**EDITED

```py
class ExtendJWTToResponse:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.
        
        jwt_token = get_authorization_header(request).decode('utf-8')
        new_jwt_token = None
        try:
            payload = jwt.decode(jwt_token, settings.SECRET_KEY)
            new_jwt_token = JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER(payload)
        except  PyJWTError:
            pass
            
        response = self.get_response(request)

        # Code to be executed for each request/response after
        # the view is called.
        if new_jwt_token:
            response['Refresh-Token'] = new_jwt_token

        return response
```

And the client must check on 'Refresh-Token' header on response and if there is any it should replace the token and use the newly issued token with the extended lifetime.
note: it is better to throttle issuing new tokens, for example, every time the request token is going to expire in the next 20 minutes...

Comment: Are "get_token_from_reques" and "check_jwt_is_valid" functions I would write or are they provided by the Django REST framework?

Comment: @Dave they were metaphors and you must write them, for the "get_token_from_request" you have used  "get_authorization_header" before, and for "check_jwt_is_valid" you have used "jwt.decode"

Comment: I have edited the answer so it uses the real functions now :)))

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I'd recommend to prefer [djangorestframework-simplejwt](https://github.com/jazzband/djangorestframework-simplejwt) over [django-rest-framework-jwt](https://github.com/jpadilla/django-rest-framework-jwt) (which is not maintained).

Both have these views basically:

- *Obtain token view (ie. login)*, takes credentials and returns a pair of access and refresh tokens
- *Refresh token view*, takes a valid refresh token and returns a refreshed access token

You'll have 2 different lifetimes for your tokens. Your access token typically lives for a few minutes whereas your refresh token would stand as long as you'd like your session to be valid.

The access token is used to prove your authentication. When expired, you should request another one thanks to the refresh view. If your refresh token is not valid (expired or blacklisted), you can wipe the authentication state on your client and ask for credentials again to obtain a new pair.

By default, when you authenticate you'll have a refresh token valid until a fixed expiry. Once reached, even if you're active, you'll need to authenticate again.

If you need a slightly short lived session, you may want to mimic Django's [`SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#session-save-every-request) to postpone the session's expiry. You can achieve this by rotating refresh tokens: when you request a new token to your refresh view, it will issue both renewed access and refresh tokens, and the refresh one would have its expiry postponed. This is covered by `djangorestframework-simplejwt` thanks to the [`ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS`](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#rotate-refresh-tokens) setting.

Comment: Thanks for the note about the deprecated library.  Regarding, "Once reached, even if you're active, you'll need to authenticate again", this isn't what I want.  I want a session to expire after one hour of inactivity.  If a user continues to make requests to valid endpoints, I want the session to be continued without them having to login.  I would prefer not to submit two tokens in the "Authorization" header for each request but I guess I'm open if that absolutely cannot be achieved.